# HBase & Snappy: CompressionTest Succeeds but Table Create Fails

Tags: linux, hadoop

I'm working with a fresh install of HBase 2.1.4 w/ Hadoop 3.1.2 on RHEL 7.6.

In HBase shell, I can create a non-compressed table no problem but this command: `create 'testtable', {NAME => 'cf', COMPRESSION => 'SNAPPY'}` enters a loop of throwing: `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.DoNotRetryIOException: java.lang.RuntimeException: native snappy library not available: this version of libhadoop was built without snappy support`.

HOWEVER

- `hbase <path>.CompressionTest mytable snappy` returns `SUCCESS`
- `hadoop checknative -a` returns `snappy: true /lib64/libsnappy.so.1`
- yum shows snappy & snappy-devel rpms are installed. (v 1.1.0-3)

So what gives? Is there some configuration I'm missing?

Answer (score 0):

Answering my own q. In hbase-env.sh, appending to a couple paths did the trick:

> export JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH=$JAVA_LIBRARY_PATH:$MY_HADOOP_PATH/lib/native
>
> export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$LD_LIBRARY_PATH:$MY_HADOOP_PATH/lib/native